# Rで生成したデータの前処理

Tags: r, dplyr

Rでいろいろな次数についてモデルのAICを計算させ

```
for(p in 1:k){
  for(q in 1:k){
:  
  aic <- infocriteria(fit)
  answer<-cbind(p,q,r,aic)
  print(answer)
}}
```

のように出力させているのですが、次数が高く最初に計算したものがコンソールから消えてしまいます。自動化させたいので変数を設定して格納させようとか考えているのですがどのような方法が考えられますでしょうか？

また、出力結果ですが、

```
             p q r s         
Akaike       1 1 1 1 4.07
Bayes        1 1 1 1 4.08
Shibata      1 1 1 1 4.08
Hannan-Quinn 1 1 1 1 4.08
             p q r s         
Akaike       1 1 1 2 4.08
Bayes        1 1 1 2 4.08
Shibata      1 1 1 2 4.07
Hannan-Quinn 1 1 1 2 4.08
:
```

のようにp q r sの部分が繰り返し出てくるのが邪魔なのですがどのように対処すればよろしいでしょうか。今流行り？のdplyrなどを使えばよいでしょうか？

**（追記）**
計算させてリストの中身を表示させようと

> print(lst)

としたら

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]

Akaike       1 1 1 1 4.107875
Bayes        1 1 1 1 4.111026
Shibata      1 1 1 1 4.107875
Hannan-Quinn 1 1 1 1 4.108906

[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]]

Akaike       1 1 1 2 4.100747
Bayes        1 1 1 2 4.104686
Shibata      1 1 1 2 4.100747
Hannan-Quinn 1 1 1 2 4.102036


[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]]

Akaike       1 1 2 1 4.103414
Bayes        1 1 2 1 4.106959
Shibata      1 1 2 1 4.103414
Hannan-Quinn 1 1 2 1 4.104574

[[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]]

Akaike       1 1 2 2 4.095238
Bayes        1 1 2 2 4.099571
Shibata      1 1 2 2 4.095238
Hannan-Quinn 1 1 2 2 4.096656
```

のようになりました。リストの中を見てcsvなどに出力し直すにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

```
write.csv
```

でしょうか？

**（再追記）**
dplyrの方式ですと

```
f <- function(p,q,r,s) {  
hogehoge

print(aic.sg)
}
params <- expand.grid(p = 1:1, q = 1:1, r = 1:3, s = 1:2)

params %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(aic = f(p, q, r, s))
```

のように記述し、

```
Error: incompatible size (4), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1
```

のエラーが返ってきます。
functionの返り値が

```
Akaike       4.108074
Bayes        4.112013
Shibata      4.108074
Hannan-Quinn 4.109363
```

のように4行に渡っていることがimcompatibleと言われてしまう原因なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リストを使うのはいかがでしょうか。

```
lst <- list()
for(p in 1:k){
  plist <- list()
  for(q in 1:k) {
    qlist <- list()
    for(r in 1:k) {
      rlist <- list()
      for(s in 1:k) {
        aic <- infocriteria(fit)
        rlist[[s]] <- cbind(p, q, r, s, aic, deparse.level = 0)
      }
      qlist[[r]] <- rlist
    }
    plist[[q]] <- qlist
  }
  lst[[p]] <- plist
}
```

リスト `lst` に結果が格納されて、`p, q, r, s` がリストの suffix になります。また、

> p q r sの部分が繰り返し出てくるのが邪魔なのですが、

これは列ラベルですので、`cbind` で `deparse.level = 0` を設定することで非表示にできます。

CSV 形式でファイルに保存するには、まず `lst` を平坦化(flatten)します。それから `write.table` でデータをファイルに保存します。

```
flatList <- unlist(unlist(unlist(lst, recursive=F), recursive=F), recursive=F)
output <- file("output.csv", open="w")    
truncate(output)
for(i in 1:length(flatList)){
  write.table(flatList[[i]], file=output, append=T, sep=",", col.names=F)
}
close(output)
```

**追記**

4重ループになると可読性が悪くなりますね… 効率的な書き方を思い付いたらまた更新します。

**追記その2**

別の方法を思い付きました。

まず、予め全ての `p, q, r, s` の組み合わせを作ってしまいます。

```
# p = 1, q = 1, r = 1:2, s = 1:4 の場合(1:1 は 1 でも可)
comb <- expand.grid(1:1, 1:1, 1:2, 1:4)
comb <- comb[order(comb[,1], comb[,2], comb[,3], comb[,4]),]
lst <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(comb)) {
  p = comb[i,1]; q = comb[i,2]; r = comb[i,3]; s = comb[i,4]
           :
  aic <- infocriteria(fit)
  lst[[i]] <- cbind(p, q, r, s, aic, deparse.level = 0)
}
```

計算結果を CSV 形式でファイルに保存する場合は以下の様にします。

```
output <- file("output.csv", open="w")    
truncate(output)
for(i in 1:length(lst)){
  write.table(lst[[i]], file=output, append=T, sep=",", col.names=F)
}
close(output)
```

出力先は `output.csv` としています(適宜変更して下さい)。`write.table` を使っているのは、`write.csv` ですと追記(append)ができないためです。

※ データを見る場合は `print` ではなく、

```
page(lst, m="p")
```

とすると `more` や `less` コマンドと同じ操作性で扱えますので便利ですよ。

Comment: 前回も質問に答えてくださってありがとうございます。
私の質問が悪かったのかうまく回ってくれません。
変数はp,q,r,sの4つで、
    lst <- list()
    for(p in 1:k){
      plist <- list()
      for(q in 1:k) {
      for(r in 1:k) {
      for(s in 1:k) {
　　　　:
      aic <- infocriteria(fit)
      plist[[s]]<-cbind(p,q,r,s,aic,deparse.level=0)
        　　}
          }
    　　}
    lst[[p]] <- plist
       }

のように書いてみたのですが回りません。
どこを直せばよいでしょうか？

Comment: 4重ループなのですね、了解です。それではそれに合わせて回答を書き直します。

Comment: わざわざ有り難うございます。
これでも回りさえすれば問題無いです。
data.frameとかでもいけないかなとかも含め自分でも考えて見ます。

Comment: csvなどのデータセットとして出力もしたいです。
追記に若干書いておきました。
時間のある時で良いのでご教示おねがいします。

Comment: page(lst, m="p")　とすると「この種類のファイルを開くにはどのアプリを使いますか」と出てきます。また、本を何冊か調べたりネットもググりましたがpage関数はなかなか出てきません。

ちなみにwin8.1です。

Comment: また、前のpqrsでループを回すプログラムでoutput.csvも試してみましたが全部データが横に並んでしまいました。
あらかじめpqrsのパターンを用意するプログラムの場合pqrsはすべて同じ数値でないとダメなのでしょうか？(1124とかにするとエラーになりました。）

Comment: すみません、少し調べてみたら Windows ではデフォルトでは page 関数が使えない様です。`options(pager = 'more')` とすれば DOS 窓で `more.com` が使える様ですが、あまり使い勝手が良くないみたいです。

Comment: @user87562  p,q,r,s が異なる場合について、書き直してみました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: お馴染みのエラー
Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.1761e-41　
が出ました。　次数は直してみたのですが。まあ上のfor文でやっても構わないです。ありがとうございました。むしろcsvが横に並ばず自動で改行されるコードを知りたいです。

Comment: @user87562  4重ループの場合の保存方法について追記しました。ただ、後の方法でエラーになるのが少し気掛かりではありますが…

Comment: 無事綺麗な形で出力できました。
改行した形とされていない形ではコードのどこが違ったのでしょうか？
unlistしたかしていないかですか？あまり使ったことのないコマンドなので質問ばかりしてすいません。

Comment: @user87562  はい、unlist で多重リストを vector の様なフラットな構造に変換したわけです。ただ、unlist を (次元数-1) 回分繰り返す必要があるのでそこが面倒ですね…

Answer (score 1):

これは必要以上にネストを深くしすぎていると思います。

詳しくないのですが、`p,q,r,s`を引数に取ってモデルのAICを返す関数をつくって、それに次数の組を渡すようなやり方ではだめなのでしょうか？ `expand.grid()`で変数の組み合わせをつくれます。わかりやすく`for`文で書くならこんな感じです。

```
f <- function(p,q,r,s) {
  ...略...
  fit <- lm(...)
  infocriteria(fit)
}

params <- expand.grid(p = 1:k_p, q = 1:k_q, r = 1:k_r, s = 1:k_s)

result <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(params)) {
  param <- params[i,]
  param$aic <- f(param$p, param$q, param$r, param$s)

  result[[i]] <- param
}

do.call(rbind, result)
```

`lapply`を使うなら、おそらくこんな感じです。

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(1:nrow(params), function(i) {
          param <- params[i,]
          param$aic <- f(param$p, param$q, param$r, param$s)
          param
        }))
```

dplyrならたぶんこれだけで済むはずです。

```
params %>%
  mutate(aic = f(p, q, r, s))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。dplyrの場合はf <- function(p,q,r,s) {
  ...略...｝の後にparams %>%…でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: エラーが出ました。Error: wrong result size (4), expected 6 or 1
また、次のエラーも出るのですがfunctionの中にif文を入れるとまずいのでしょうか？
In addition: Warning message:
In if (s == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: 調べたらifは長さ1の要素しか受け取れないとかで1:2みたいなのがまずいようですね…

Comment: lapplyだと「置換は 4 列ですが、データは 1 列です」 とのエラーが出てきます…

Comment: すみません、おっしゃる通り長さ1の要素しか受け取れないのでだめですね。うっかりしていました。。
1行づつの処理になるので、`rowwise()`が必要です。

    `params %>%
      rowwise %>%
      mutate(aic = f(p, q, r, s))`

Answer (score 0):

> (再追記）
>   dplyrの方式ですと
>   　　　:
>   のように4行に渡っていることがimcompatibleと言われてしまう原因なのでしょうか？

まず、`f` function の最後の `print(aic.sg)` を `aic.sg` に変更します(`print(aic.sg)` のままでも構わないのですが、画面表示の必要はないと思われますので)。

```
f <- function(p,q,r,s) {  
  hogehoge
     :
  aic.sg
}
```

dplyr は使った事がないのでどうも勝手が良く分からないのですが、以下の様にするのではないでしょうか。

```
> dd <- params %>%
    rowwise %>%
      do({
        v <- f(p, q, r, s)
        data.frame(name=rownames(v), ., v)
      }) %>% print()

Source: local data frame [24 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

           name     p     q     r     s       V1
         (fctr) (int) (int) (int) (int)    (dbl)
1        Akaike     1     1     1     1 1.124508
2         Bayes     1     1     1     1 1.141493
3       Shibata     1     1     1     1 1.124490
4  Hannan-Quinn     1     1     1     1 1.130749
5        Akaike     1     1     2     1 1.124508
6         Bayes     1     1     2     1 1.141493
7       Shibata     1     1     2     1 1.124490
8  Hannan-Quinn     1     1     2     1 1.130749
                            :
```

※ V1 の値は適当です

なお、CSV 形式でのファイル出力は以下の様になります。

```
> write.table(dd, file="output.csv", sep=",", row.names=F, col.names=F)
```